# overflow hidden doesn't work with percentage width

Tags: html, css, containers, overflow

I've a problem with the overflow hidden, it doesn't work at all with my container percentage width, here an example of the html and css structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box-overflow">
        <div class="box-overflow-inner" style="width: 3680px; left: 0px; display: block; position: relative;">
          <div class="box-item">
          </div>
          <div class="box-item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know it is quite nested but here it is the css:

```
.container { width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
.container-inner { width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
.box-container { width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
.box-overflow { overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; }
```

The problem seems with the 'container' element, if I add a fixed width everything seems to work correctly, but with a percentage width, all the contents takes the 3680px and I don't know why.

Any help it'd really appreciated!

Thank you all!

Comment: have you tried with width: auto?

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the error?

Comment: I don't really see the problem. No matter if I change the width for the outer container, it keeps behaving as expected. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMQVbo). Is the problem that you expect the width of .overflow-inner to become less than 3680px wide in the output?

Comment: Hello guys, thank you all! I finally found the solution, the problem was caused by the display:flex; style added to another parent element!